# Packaging Font Awesome font files in a separate directory with Webpack 2

Tags: npm, webpack, font-awesome, webpack-2

I am attempting to use Webpack 2 and Font Awesome in a  Cordova application. The Cordova application generates a file structure like this:

```
app
config.xml
hooks
node_modules
package.json
platforms
plugins
webpack.config.js
www
```

(This naturally includes my NPM files and webpack configuration, for context. `app` is where I squirrel away the raw JSX source code).

The structure under `www` (which is where the compiled out web application should go), looks like this:

```
css
fonts
img
index.html
js
```

I created the `fonts` directory as a target for the webpack configuration. The problem that I am running into is that I can either have the fonts copied to some useful location under the root or I can have the filtered CSS correct, but not both.

For example, if I use an example like the one below:

```
        {
            test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&outputPath=www/fonts/&publicPath=/fonts/"
        }
```

The files get placed under `www`, but the compiled source comes out strange.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url(/fonts/www/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot);
  src: url(/fonts/www/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0) format('embedded-opentype'), url(/fonts/www/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2) format('woff2'), url(/fonts/www/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff) format('woff'), url(/fonts/www/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf) format('truetype'), url(/fonts/www/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular) format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I have yet to be able to find a happy medium with the file loader when trying to place fonts under `www`. The recommendations in [How to configure font file output directory from font-awesome-webpack in webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34014151/how-to-configure-font-file-output-directory-from-font-awesome-webpack-in-webpack) and [Can't load font-awesome with Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482692/cant-load-font-awesome-with-webpack) really have not gotten me anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `outputPath` option in the `file-loader` is relative to your output directory and therefore will be included in the path. And `publicPath` just adds the given path to the beginning of the used paths, it basically means that the output directory will be located somewhere else on the server. This leaves the original path unchanged, since the structure within the directory must be unchanged.

To make it work as you described, you need to change how you handle the output directory. As you've already mentioned your output directory is `www`, that's where webpack should put everything. Therefore it makes sense to configure [`output.path`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-path) to `www`.

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'www'),
  // Other output options
}
```

With this you don't need to specify `www` in every output name/path. For instance you might have done something along these lines: `filename: 'www/bundle.js`, this now becomes just `filename: 'bundle.js'`. Even though the result is the same, the concept behind it is different, because you just tell webpack where to put the output files, but only the filename itself is relevant for any processing, whereas the output directory is irrelevant.

Now you have to change the `outputPath` in the `file-loader` to `fonts/` and without the `publicPath` you would get the following URL:

```
url(fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot);
```

That's a relative path, and you probably want to make it a server-relative path. The only thing that is missing is the leading `/`, therefore you'd set the `publicPath` to `/` and your rule becomes (using the nicer webpack 2 syntax instead of inlining the options, which makes it easier to read):

```
{
  test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
    name: '[name].[ext]',
    outputPath: 'fonts/',
    publicPath: '/'
  }
}
```

You'll probably want other loaders, that include assets, to also respect the same public path, so instead of defining it per loader, you can set it in [`output.publicPath`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-publicpath).

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'www'),
  publicPath: '/',
  // Other output options
}
```

Comment: Setting the output path was the key. Thanks!